# Login Facebook App can't any infomation of user

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I have a problem with my app login with facebook SDK (web using codeigniter)

First, login ok with query data of user logged, but only email of user that I can't get it,

So, I added scope to `$this->facebook->getLoginUrl('scope'=>'email')` to get email, and then, I got email, But the problem is, I got nothing when I added code below:

```
$this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email','redirect_uri' => $mycurrent_url))
```

redirect_uri to my current_url is corrected, but failed to get data.
**what I want is, get all data with redirect_uri!**

Please, see the code:

```
$user = $this->facebook->getUser();

    if($user) {

        try {

            $user_info = $this->facebook->api('/me');

            $args = $logout_url;

    $data['getLogoutUrl'] = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl($args);

    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
            $user = null;
        }
    } else {

   $param = array('scope' => 'email','redirect_uri' => $mycurrent_url);

       $data['getURLLogin'] = "<a href=\"".$this->facebook->getLoginUrl($param)."\">Login with facebook</a>";

    }
```

what's wrong with this code?

thank for help in advance.

Comment: I don't see how you try to get the data. PS: haven't you forgotten `array()` around parameters?

Comment: Sorry, my question is wrong,now edited

Comment: "But the problem is, I got nothing when I added code below" -- please elaborate this. What "nothing" exactly means?

Comment: The problem is, $user didn't get data , meaning that, if($user) { code is not running }

Comment: could you show us facebook->GetUser() Wouldn't you need to pass along a userID or email address to tell facebook which user you want to get

Comment: Actually, problem is, when I put $param = array('scope' => 'email');

no redirect_uri is ok (can get data), but if I put 'redirect_uri' => $mycurrent_url, the code is not working!

Comment: can you show us getLoginUrl() then

Comment: $param = array('scope' => 'email,read_stream','redirect_uri'=>$myurl);
$data['getURLLogin'] = "<a href=\"".$this->facebook->getLoginUrl($param)."\">